# Why cmake and make inside dockerfile does not do anything

Tags: docker, cmake, makefile, dockerfile, containers

I have following lines in docker file:

```
WORKDIR /my_ws 

# clone opencv
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
    
# clone opencv_contrib
RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git

# build opencv
WORKDIR /my_ws/opencv 
RUN sudo mkdir -p /my_ws/opencv/build
WORKDIR /my_ws/opencv/build
RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON .. &> cmake.log
RUN make -j4 &> make.log
RUN make install &> make-install.log

WORKDIR /my_ws
```

I built the image as follows:

```
docker build . --no-cache --progress plain -t my_co:my_prod &> docker-build.log
```

`docker-build.log` contains following lines:

```
#11 [11/44] WORKDIR /my_ws
#11 DONE 0.0s

#12 [12/44] RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git
#12 0.321 Cloning into 'opencv'...
#12 DONE 36.5s

#16 [13/44] RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git
#16 0.463 Cloning into 'opencv_contrib'...
#16 DONE 9.7s

#27 [14/44] WORKDIR /my_ws/opencv
#27 DONE 0.0s

#28 [15/44] RUN sudo mkdir -p /my_ws/opencv/build
#28 DONE 0.3s

#29 [16/44] WORKDIR /my_ws/opencv/build
#29 DONE 0.0s

#30 [17/44] RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.prefix)") -D PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D PYTHON_DEFAULT_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) -D WITH_GTK=ON -D WITH_FFMPEG=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D HAVE_opencv_python3=ON .. &> cmake.log
#30 DONE 0.5s

#31 [18/44] RUN make -j4 &> make.log
#31 DONE 0.4s

#32 [19/44] RUN make install &> make-install.log
#32 DONE 0.4s
```

I run the dockerfile as follows:

```
docker run -d --name my_container my_co:my_prod
```

When I checked inside vscode's container browser, the opencv directory inside the docker container does indeed contained build folder, but none other build artifacts apart from the log files which I explicitly created inside dockerfile:

[image]

Also all of these log files were empty! :

```
 *  Executing task: docker exec -it 572d39fd1653a9f54d848e2936aabc4a7d13b93a661538b20fb09156e5570351 bash 

root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws# cd ./opencv/build/
root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws/opencv/build# ls
cmake.log  make-install.log  make.log
root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws/opencv/build# cat cmake.log 
root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws/opencv/build# cat make-install.log 
root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws/opencv/build# cat make.log 
root@572d39fd1653:/my_ws/opencv/build#
```

When I manually copy paste and run those `cmake`, `make` and `make install` commands inside running container by attaching shell to it, they starts generating the corresponding build artefacts and logging corresponding progress to above log files!

Then why these opencv building is not happening while building the image through dockerfile? What I am missing here?

PS: this is based on Ubuntu20:04 image

Comment: What happens if you run the commands without the log redirection?  `&>` is a bashism, so without doing any research I'd be unsure if docker supports it while building images.